# HTACCESS With exception for certain folders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I have an old website i'm trying to take over, and it has a bad htaccess file here that I need to adjust to enable 'FOLDERS', instead of routing EVERYTHING.

So I have a folder called, "RESOURCES", but it's trying to route through the index file with it..... but I need to load the resource folder instead of routing. How do I make an exception?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.website.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(browse)/?$ /browse.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\ \+\-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ /index.php?where=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^([\ \+\-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ /index.php?where=$1&what=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ /index.php?where=$1&what=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule just below `RewriteBase /`

```
RewriteRule ^RESOURCES/- [L,NC]
```

This will skip rest of the rewrite rules for folder called `RESOURCES`

To skip all the folders use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^- [L]
```

Comment: Awesome... thanks... appreciate that. Just as a side-question, is there a Dynamic thing that I could add, for any FOLDER, visit it, vs using the rewrite?

Comment: Well... think again... What if some folder has name `RESOURCES2`?

Comment: @Ωmega: There should have been a slash after folder name like: `RewriteRule ^RESOURCES/ - [L,NC]`